# How to change the numbering of ordered files?

Tags: linux, rename

I have a set of files such as "surfgrid.3.h5" to "surfgrid.14.h5" and I need them to be ordered from "surfgrid.1.h5" to "surfgrid.12.h5". I have the same issue with different starting point (it is not always starting from 3).

I tried several solutions for similar problems but they do not work in this case. Also some tests renamed first the files from 10 to 14 and then 3 to 9 altering the order that is fundamental for me.

I use a machine that works with Linux.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you want them to be ordered? Like print them out in order?

Comment: @BenjaminCommet I think he just wants to take a set of filenames that have gaps in the number, and rename them so they're consecutive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the piece of code below should do the job for you.

```
Start=3
End=14
echo "\$Start = " $Start " and \$End = " $End
for i in $(seq $Start $End);

  do 
    echo " i is $i"
    j=$((i-2)) 
    echo " j is $j"
    cp surfgrid.$i.h5 surfgrid.$j.h5
  done
```

Comment: This works perfectly. It keeps the original order of the files.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Increment a variable and use that in place of the number in the filenames.

I rename them initially into another directory to avoid problems with name clashes between the old names and new names.

```
mkdir temp
i=1
for file in surfgrid.*.h5
do
    mv "$file" "temp/surfgrid.$i.h5"
    ((i++))
done
mv temp/* .
```

When the shell expands the wildcard `surfgrid.*.h5`, it's ordered lexicographically, not numerically, so `sufgrid.10.h5` comes before `sufgrid.2.h5`. See [Glob with Numerical Order](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38317/glob-with-numerical-order) 
  for a number of solutions to this.

Comment: Thanks, the program works but it doesn't keep the right order. What I get is:

10 --> 1
...
14 --> 5,
3   --> 6
...
9   --> 12.

Comment: The question doesn't say anything about how the result order should relate to the original names.

Comment: When a wildcard is expanded, the shell uses lexicographic order, not numeric order.

Comment: I've added a link to another question that explains how to get numeric ordering of wildcard results.

Comment: When I say "the order that is fundamental for me" I mean that 3 has to become 1, 4 become 2 and so on. I hope it is clear now.

Is there any possible way to make this change?

Comment: I hope my link to the other question will help you with that part of it.